# Python format inside brackets

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, formatting

Is it possible to format inside of the brackets? What I mean is this:

```
print "Formatting: { 0 : {1} s }".format("""\
long piece of text that I need to format, but I can't explicitly say\
how long it is going to be because it is coming from another function\
that gives me the length of how many characters I can print. So, it would be\
really helpful if someone could help me with this""" , charMax())

import random

def charMax():
    return random.randint(10, 80)
```

Can anyone help me establish how to emulate the sudo code above?

Comment: Have you tried it yet?

Comment: Yes. Let me double check my syntax

Comment: Try ditching the spaces.

Comment: Hm. It doesn't throw an error, but it doesn't limit the string like I want it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formatting specifier is wrong. String length restriction is governed by the *precision*.

```
"{0:.{1}s}".format(...)
```

Comment: thanks. Why do you need the `.`. I was certain that you only needed the period for floats and ints...

Comment: The `.` is the separator between the width and the precision. For strings, the width is the *minimum* and the precision is the maximum.

Answer (score 0):

Better to put the *length* in *first*, and use the `.length` *precision* formatting to limit the length:

```
"Formatting: {1:.{0}s}".format(charMax(), """Some long string""")
```

Now the string is formatted to a *maximum* length rather than a minimum:

```
>>> some_long_string = """\
... long piece of text that I need to format, but I can't explicitly say\
... how long it is going to be because it is coming from another function\
... that gives me the length of how many characters I can print. So, it would be\
... really helpful if someone could help me with this"""
>>> print "Formatting: {1:.{0}s}".format(charMax(), some_long_string)
Formatting: long piece of text that I need to format, bu
>>> print "Formatting: {1:.{0}s}".format(charMax(), some_long_string)
Formatting: long piece of text that I need to format, but I can't explicitly 
>>> print "Formatting: {1:.{0}s}".format(charMax(), some_long_string)
Formatting: long piece of text that I
```

It'll work with the orders reversed too:

```
>>> print "Formatting: {0:.{1}s}".format(some_long_string, charMax())
Formatting: long piece of text that I need to format, but I can't ex
```

But its clearer for the reader to see what is happening the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely need a function if you want a string of desired length, `format`s aren't going to do much for you:

```
def charMax():
    return random.randint(10, 80)

def stringLength(originalStr, length):
    return originalStr[:length]
```

And *then* you can do the formatting:

```
print "Formatting: {0}".format(stringLength("long piece of text that I need to format, but I can't explicitly say how long it is going to be because it is coming from another function that gives me the length of how many characters I can print. So, it would be really helpful if someone could help me with this", charMax()))
```

---

```
>>> print "Formatting: {0}".format(stringLength("long piece of text that I need to format, but I can't explicitly say how long it is going to be because it is coming from another function that gives me the length of how many characters I can print. So, it would be really helpful if someone could help me with this", charMax()))
Formatting: long piece of text that I need to format, 
>>> print "Formatting: {0}".format(stringLength("long piece of text that I need to format, but I can't explicitly say how long it is going to be because it is coming from another function that gives me the length of how many characters I can print. So, it would be really helpful if someone could help me with this", charMax()))
Formatting: long piece of text that I n
>>> print "Formatting: {0}".format(stringLength("long piece of text that I need to format, but I can't explicitly say how long it is going to be because it is coming from another function that gives me the length of how many characters I can print. So, it would be really helpful if someone could help me with this", charMax()))
Formatting: long piece of text that I need to format, but I can't expl
>>> print "Formatting: {0}".format(stringLength("long piece of text that I need to format, but I can't explicitly say how long it is going to be because it is coming from another function that gives me the length of how many characters I can print. So, it would be really helpful if someone could help me with this", charMax()))
Formatting: long piece of text that I nee
>>>
```